# How to calculate pause interval in an XML file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file with the following information:

```
<Key Time="54288" Type="insert" Value="E" />

<Key Time="55288" Type="insert" Value="A" />

<Key Time="58298" Type="insert" Value="O" />
```

I need to calculate the total pause duration between each Key entry, but only when the pauses (the interval between one "Time" and the other) are equal to or higher than 2400. Can someone help me with a Perl script for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this "one-liner"

```
perl -nle '
   /<Key +Time\s*=\s*"([0-9]+)\s*"/ and push @nums,$1; 
   END{ 
       for(1..$#nums){ 
           $pause=$nums[$_]-$nums[$_-1];
           $pause >=2400 ? print "$pause started at ".$nums[$_-1] : ()
       }
   }' your_file_here > output_file
```

This saves the program's output into the file `output_file`. You can open this file with any spreadsheet software and it will automatically know to place the output in one table column.

Comment: Thank you very much you both. I know it is a silly question, but how can I make it provide the results for a batch of files (the sum for each file).

Comment: I have tried with a larger file. The code provides the largest pause, but not the sum of the pauses. What should I change?

Comment: Actually, I found out that the I have some brackets that have variable "Time", but are not Key, for example: "<Other Time="10045">". How can I ignore this?

Comment: @ials See if this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now. If you don't mind, can you tell me if it's possible to get the results in an excel file or excel-readable file? Or is it at least possible to get the results split according to files they come from?

Comment: @ials Please see the updated answer. I'm not sure what you mean by "according to files they come from", I was under the impression you had only one XML file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As for your concern, I have a batch of files and I would like to compile all information more easily.

Comment: Dear Joseph R., is it possible to get the exact time each pause begins?

Comment: I've got a question. It works pretty well on Mac Terminal. How can I possibly make it work on Windows? I have tried with Active Perl and Strawberry Perl, and I get that the particular parts of the script (e.g., $pause=$nums[$_]-$nums
[$_-1];) are not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: @ials I think on Windows you need to swap double quotes with single quotes and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open data.xml ;
for //Key[preceding-sibling::Key] {
    $pause = @Time - preceding-sibling::Key[1]/@Time ;
    if ($pause >= 2400) echo $pause ;
}
```

Output:

```
3010
```

Comment: I get this output: Bareword found where operator expected at teste.pl line 5, near ") echo"
 (Missing operator before echo?)
syntax error at teste.pl line 3, near "for //"
syntax error at teste.pl line 5, near ") echo "
Execution of teste.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @ials: Have you installed xsh? Have you read its documentation?

Comment: sure, I installed XSH2. I have figured out some of my mistakes, but I am still trying to do it.

Comment: @ials: Either run the script with `xsh script.xsh`, or include it in a perl script with `xsh q{ ... }`.

Comment: @ials Have you tried using `print` instead of `echo`? `echo` is a shell command. I think this is a typo.

Comment: @JosephR.: This is `xsh`, not standard Perl.